# C# client - flask python app HTTP post error

Tags: python, c#, flask

I am creating an app in using .NET (C#) platform that will allow me to upload images to a python app running on flask to be stored at the local level for further processing. Currently, I am getting the following error (please see below).

Python:

```
import os
from flask import Flask,request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"] = '../confidence'


@app.route('/uploadData', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upLoadData():
    if request.method == "POST":
     
        image = request.files["image"]
      
        image.save(os.path.join(app.config["IMAGE_UPLOADS"], image.filename))

        print("Image saved")
        
        
    return ""
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestPostExample
    {
        public static void Request()
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.199:8080/uploadData");
            request.Method = "POST";

        string postData = @"C:\Users\HFRANYIE\Documents\localAIML\src\resized.jpg";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentType ="image";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

        using (dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        }

        response.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Error:
[image]

Comment: You do realize you're getting bytes from a string and not an image right?

Comment: @zaggler Yes, I do. But I suspect from the output that the error is being generated due to the Key type and not the data type. I mean, I can change it to string and still will get the same error.